# extranet/anonymous user can not preview the specific language version of an item (with default security settings)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have different language-versions of an item and all of them can be previewed, but only one - not. I am always redirecting to home page, if I am trying to preview this particular version. After redirecting I can see in log file the following record: "ERROR Item could not be found from query string."

[image]

As I know, it means, that the preview user "extranet/anonymouse" has no rights to read this version of item. I have checked the security rights of extranet/anonymouse for this item (clicked "details" on security tab) and found, that no special rights were assigned to this item.

[image]

After assigning the read rights manually, the previewing works well. But per default not. For other versions I don't need to assign the read rights manually. How can I solve these preview problems?

UPDATE: all languages are disabled for extranet/anonymous, but it has influence only on en-AU
[image]

Comment: Is your screenshot accurate to when you are reproducing the error? According to the message, you have no version in en-AW. Have you created a version yet?

Comment: Sounds like you have the “Language Read” right denied for the en-AU language. To check it: open the Access Viewer application, select the “extranet/anonymous” account , click the “Columns” command, select “Language Read”, expand /sitecore/system/Languages node to see current language permissions. If it is so, you need to allow the access using the Security Editor application

Comment: @Vladimir you are right, the current permission for "language read" set to "disabled", but it is so for all languages. And all other languages work well. Only en-AU doesn't work.

Comment: I have another idea. What if that language version has any publishing restrictions? Let’s say the standard field “Hide version” is checked.  In this case, the default Preview mode will not be able to find that item as well.

Comment: @Vladimir, no, hide version is not checked :(